# RD mail form. Problem with hide error text in another input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dom, mail-form

Is there anyone who has worked with rd mail form?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsman82/n48o73k1/65/)

There is an instruction

```
e(this).removeClass("error").removeClass("show").addClass("hide").parent().trigger("mfValidator.click").find(t._core.options.validator.applyTo).focus()
```

that hides the error text when clicked, but I can't figure out how to get to the error text in another field, such as name and hide it if the user clicked on the error text in the email field. Can someone give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the error from all input first and then add it to the specific input you clicked. In you case I am seen that the `error` class has been added to span. Try below

`e('span').removeClass("error")`

And then add your code

`e(this).removeClass("error").removeClass("show").addClass("hide").parent().trigger("mfValidator.click").find(t._core.options.validator.applyTo).focus()`

This give it a try!

Comment: It's hide all errors, but how to hide error only in email input field? I tried to make an id for each span by e(this).parent().append(e("<span id='+this.name+'/>", {"class": t._care.options.validator["class"]})) and hide it by id, but the form didn't work. What am I doing wrong?